# Spring + OpenSessionInView doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and would like to use `OpenSessionInView` so I do not have to implement my `Filter`.

file web.xml

```
<!-- openSessionInView SpringMVC -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>        
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- FIM openSessionInView SpringMVC -->
```

Even putting the `OpenSessionInView` declaration in the web.xml file, the system returns me the session error when I use the `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`

```
Exception returned
type Exception report

message org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.pedidos.entities.Representante.listUser, no session or session was closed
```

thanks

Comment: I would highly recommend against using this filter in any project beyond something considered an example/demo/toy.  This approach essentially advocates bad design practices and poor design choices, imposes higher overhead on database resources as connections must remain open longer, and can often lead to mistakes where database rows end up being modified in some way due to code in a controller or a view page rather than being confined inside a service or repository/dao method only.

Comment: if your view requires entity A with a list of entity B, then ask your repository for precisely that.  Specific, concrete queries will always perform better than any type of dynamic / open session/entitymanager in view solution.